# Please remove scrollbar-width: thin from code blocks AND fix the missing ends

Tags: feature-request, design, code

Horizontal scrolling of code blocks is *a thing* to say the least.

```
foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz

foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz foo bar baz buzz
```

With the most recent addition of `scrollbar-width: thin`, it is a pain to hit the scrollbar with the mouse to perform it. Just try it with the code above.

Vertical scrolling is a struggle too, but at least can be easily performed with the mouse wheel when precision is not required.

Please roll back.

---

Thank you, this has been rolled back as of 2020-02-11 17:37 UTC.

However the issue now is that the color of the scrollbar track is set to transparent:

```css
scrollbar-color: var(--scrollbar) transparent;
```

which, with the now-normal scrollbar width, results in missing end arrows:

[image]

I can't help wanting to scroll it to the end, but I can't.

It's also come to my attention that this feature is [only supported in Firefox](https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollbar-), so probably too early to use it anyway.

Comment: Horizontal scrolling may be possible if you can click your mouse wheel, although that can also be annoying if both vertical and horizontal scrolling is enabled.

Comment: When I checked this on a mobile device, the scrolling worked with finger swipes but the code itself showed as three lines for each paragraph (the first two the width of the code block, the third longer) rather than one line in each paragraph that the full site (desktop) shows it as.

Comment: Another option is to hold shift, and then scroll the mouse wheel while hovering over the code, that allows horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I still see the thin scrollbar (using Chrome). Edit: just tested on FireFox and it's exactly like your screenshot (with transparent buttons).

Comment: *It might not work, but it looks phenomenal ...*

Comment: @rene I'd agree but I can barely see it since *grey but illegible is so much cooler than black but legible* ...