# Transparent scrollbars with no ends in text entry boxes look terrible

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, firefox

Maybe this is a subjective issue, but I hate how the transparent scrollbars that I see in all of the text boxes on Stack Overflow don't use all the space in the box. I don't mind how the bar itself looks, but I strongly dislike the empty space it leaves where the "arrows" on the ends of the bar should be. I didn't specifically notice when this started happening, but I feel like it changed somehow in just the last month or so. Certainly many months ago the scroll bars looked normal (with arrows on the ends), but maybe there were better functioning transparent bars that I didn't notice.

Here are two example screenshots, from the very page I'm writing this question on. The first one is from the text editing box where I'm writing this question, the second is from the Similar Questions box:

[image: transparent scroll bar on edit box]
[image: transparent scroll bar similar questions box]

Can you tell that the first is all the way at the bottom and the second is all the way to the top? The gap means I sure can't!

I'm using Firefox 73.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 10, on the off chance this is a display issue that is browser or OS specific.

I don't know CSS very well, but from what I can see this is a deliberate style choice. Firefox's Devtools show me that both classes `s-input` (used by input boxes like the one I'm typing in now) and `overflow-y-scroll` (used by the Similar Questions box I screenshotted) both have an entry setting `scrollbar-color: var(--scrollbar) transparent;`. The `transparent` part makes the ends of the bars invisible (deleting `transparent` or disabling the whole line makes them reappear).

I would strongly prefer either a traditional scrollbar with visible ends on it, or a bar that actually uses all of the space for the slider. Leaving a blank space for the invisible ends of the scrollbar is worse than either.

Comment: [Related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393820/please-remove-scrollbar-width-thin-from-code-blocks-and-fix-the-missing-ends).

Comment: I personally find more annoying the rounded ends that show in the textbox scrollbar in my particular browser (Brave).